# What do these terms stand for on my HTC RUU

Tags: htc-desire, rom, ruu

I've been tinkering around lately with my HTC desire 510 and I feel like if someone doesn't shed a bit of light on this for me I'll be going around in circles.

I'm looking at stock ROM's for my HTC. I found a massive amount of them and I want to figure out what the following terms mean/stand for on them:

-A11, A11U, A11UL, A11CHL ?

-K44, K443 ?

-SENSE60 ?

-0PCVIMG

As an example I'm looking at the following ROM update utility:

> RUU_A11_UL_K443_DESIRE_SENSE60_HTC_Europe_1.51.401.1_Radio_01.02.012_U10251_39.08.40922_release_398419_signed.EXE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A11_UL is the product number for a specific hardware variant of the Desire 510.  Other examples include HIMA_UL for the m9, M7_UL for the m7, M7C_DWG for the China version, etc.

K443 is the version of software (in this case KitKat, Android version 4.4.3). Other codes you'll see here are L50 (Lollipop 5.0), JB (Jellybean), etc.

SENSE60 means it has v6.0 of Sense, HTC's custom launcher.  I've also seen SENSE55, SENSE50, etc.

Other things indicate the carrier that the ROM was customized for, radio version contained in the RUU, etc.

Comment: Thank you for that answer! However I also noticed that the same hardware variant A11_UL is sub-divided for many different carriers, does that mean that if you take down SIM lock that hardware will support all those other carriers ?  and also how does IMEI relate to that number ?

Comment: OEMs customize both hardware and software for carriers and the RUU naming convention reflects that.  That doesn't mean the hardware is necessarily different among carriers, just that it might be.  SIM lock is something else, and if you're unlocked, you can just swap out the SIM to move to a different carrier.  You wouldn't need to (and probably shouldn't try) flashing a ROM for a different carrier.  In HTC, there's something called the CID which will prevent you from doing this, but that's another story.

Comment: The IMEI is a unique number for every device and fields within it are tied to OEMs, devices, etc. much like MAC addresses for Ethernet and WiFi.  So IMEI relates to that number at manufacture time, but doesn't have anything to do with unlocking or running software version.

Comment: You'll find more device-specific help over at xda-developers.com. I strongly recommend reading up on your device there if you want to tinker.  And also check out threads describing the tools `unruu` and `ruuveal` if you want to look inside the RUU file and get into cooking ROMs (off topic here).

Comment: Thank you Paul for giving me a lot of valuable information here, unfortunately I can't up-vote you because I just joined this forum. -> In Theory as long as I have A11_UL rom it shouldn't matter to me which carrier it is assigned to, right ?  With regards to IMEI : I remember on the older phones it had to do with unlocking a sim-lock and so I'm confused as to why you've said that "it doesn't have to do anything with unlocking..." . Also I am reading up on my device and that's the reason I'm here asking you questions - to clarify the confusion and the mist.

Comment: Sorry I just meant that the correlation between IMEI and physical device/carrier doesn't prevent you from unlocking or changing ROMs.